# Convert PDF to doc or docx format using npm/node module or via code?

Tags: node.js, npm

I haven't been successful in finding a node module or some code that can convert a PDF to doc/docx format using Node JS. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Aspose.Words Cloud SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/aspose-words-cloud/aspose-words-cloud-node) to convert PDF to DOCX from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/asposewordscloud)

```
#Convert PDF to DOCX from Cloud Storage
const { WordsApi, SaveOptionsData } = require("asposewordscloud");
const { UploadFileRequest, SaveAsRequest }= require("asposewordscloud/dist/model/model");
var fs = require('fs');

# Please get your App Key and App SID from https://dashboard.aspose.cloud
wordsApi = new WordsApi("APP_KEY", "APP_SID");

const remotename = "02_pages.pdf";
const remoteTempFolder = "Temp";

const request = new SaveAsRequest({
                        saveOptionsData: new SaveOptionsData({
                            saveFormat: "docx",
                            fileName: "TestPostDocumentSavePdfAsDocx.docx",
                        }),

                    });
                    request.name = remotename;
                    request.folder = remoteTempFolder;

wordsApi.saveAs(request).then((result) => {    
    console.log(result.body);    
}).catch(function(err) {
    // Deal with an error
    console.log(err);
});


# Convert PDF to DOCX from request stream
const { WordsApi, ConvertDocumentRequest } = require("asposewordscloud");
var fs = require('fs');

 // Get Customer ID and Customer Key from https://dashboard.aspose.cloud/
wordsApi = new WordsApi("xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

 var request = new ConvertDocumentRequest({
                format: "docx",
                document: fs.createReadStream("C:/Temp/02_pages.pdf"),
            });
 var outputFile = "C:/Temp/ConvertPDFtotxt.docx";
 wordsApi.convertDocument(request).then((result) => {    
 console.log(result.response.statusCode);    
 console.log(result.body.byteLength);    
 fs.writeFileSync(outputFile, result.body);
 }).catch(function(err) {
 // Deal with an error
 console.log(err);
 });
```

I'm developer evangelist at aspose.

Comment: is it possible to convert a generated pdf buffer to a docx file? im failing to do so

Comment: @EmilC. Aspose.Words Cloud SDK for Node.js supports converting documents from the request stream as well. I have updated my above answer with a sample code. You can try it.

Comment: thank you, when i res.send(result.body) the user is prompted to download a file without an extension, also all the formatting is messed up, some words and pics are missing

Answer (score 0):

**node-unoconv**

A node.js wrapper for converting documents with unoconv.

https://github.com/gfloyd/node-unoconv

Comment: I cant use it as it has a local dependency of libraoffice. It wouldnt work if i move code to a remote location.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this service https://docs.groupdocs.cloud/conversion/convert-document/. It allows to convert a lot of various formats.