# Best way to convert a pdf buffer into a docx file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to generate a pdf that a user can download and save. i want to be able to convert the same pdf to a docx file instead, so the user downloads a docx instead of a pdf. I cant seem to find any packages or ways to do it.

here is my code that generates a pdf buffer in Nodejs that the user can save

```
router.get(
    '/pdf',
    catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
        const url = req.session.url + '/getpdf';

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true,
            args: [ '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox' ]
        });

        const webPage = await browser.newPage();

        await webPage.goto(url, {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
        });

        const pdf = await webPage.pdf({
            printBackground: true,
            format: 'A4',
            margin: {
                top: '20px',
                right: '20px',
                bottom: '20px',
                left: '20px'
            }
        });

        await browser.close();

        res.contentType('application/pdf');
//SENDING PDF TO USER, BUT I WANT TO SEND .docx INSTEAD
        res.send(pdf);
    })
);
```

Comment: https://www.docconversionapi.com/blog/convert-pdf-to-docx-using-nodejs/

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302389/convert-pdf-to-doc-or-docx-format-using-npm-node-module-or-via-code

Comment: https://docs.groupdocs.cloud/conversion/convert-document/